# How would I rewrite .sc files into a different format?

Tags: ruby

I want to export sc files from SpaceEngine, then for each file, create a new file with the same name but with the extension `.txt`.

Here is my code:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'IO/console'

puts "Make sure your export folder is clear of everything but the files you want to turn into Object text files."
puts "Starting Process"
i = 0
Dir.foreach('C:\SpaceEngine\export') do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..'
  i = i + 1
  name = File.basename(item, ".*")
  current = File.new("#{name}.txt", "w");
  current.close
end
sleep 2
```

I have the latter part already, but I can't get it to read the original files one by one, and then only put certain things from the original into the new file.

Comment: I don't see any instruction that would read from the original files in your code, is it on purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# test.sc
# assume this is your test data
this has foo
this does not
this also has foo
this has some other stuff
this is the last line which has foo
blah
blah blah 


# filejunk.rb
# you need to write a method that handles the data inside the file you want to
# modify, change, replace etc. but for example

def replace_file_data(filename)
  lines = File.readlines
  lines.select{|l| l.include?'foo'} #assumes you only want lines with 'foo' in them
end

Dir.glob('C:\SpaceEngine\export\*.sc').each_with_index  do |filename, i|
  i += 1
  name = File.basename(filename, ".*")
  current = File.new("#{name}.txt", "w") {|f| f.write  replace_file_data(filename) }
  current.close
end
```